# What is the correct way to slice a unicode string in python?

Tags: python, json, unicode

Im new to python and playing around with the scrapy web crawler.
I want grab the first 10 characters of a description string and use these as a title

The following fragment of python code results in the JSON below

```
item['image'] = img.xpath('@src').extract()
item_desc = img.xpath('@title').extract()
print(item_desc)
item['description'] = item_desc
item['title'] = item_desc[:10]
item['parentUrl'] = response.url

{'description': [u'CHAR-BROIL Tru-Infrared 350 IR Gas Grill - SportsAuthority.com '],
 'image': [u'http://www.sportsauthority.com/graphics/product_images/pTSA-10854895t130.jpg'],
 'parentUrl': 'http://www.sportsauthority.com/category/index.jsp?categoryId=3077576&clickid=topnav_Jerseys+%26+Fan+Shop',
 'title': [u'CHAR-BROIL Tru-Infrared 350 IR Gas Grill - SportsAuthority.com ']}
```

What I would like is the below. The slice isnt behaving as Id expect.

```
{'description': [u'CHAR-BROIL Tru-Infrared 350 IR Gas Grill - SportsAuthority.com '],
 'image': [u'http://www.sportsauthority.com/graphics/product_images/pTSA-10854895t130.jpg'],
 'parentUrl': 'http://www.sportsauthority.com/category/index.jsp?categoryId=3077576&clickid=topnav_Jerseys+%26+Fan+Shop',
 'title': [u'CHAR-BROIL']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item_desc` is a *list* with one element in it, and that element is a unicode string. It is not a unicode string itself. The `[...]` are a big hint there.

Get the element out, slice, and put it back in a list:

```
item['title'] = [item_desc[0][:10]]
```

Evidently the `.extract()` function can return more than one match; you could also just pick the first one if you are expecting just one match:

```
item['image'] = img.xpath('@src').extract()[0]
item_desc = img.xpath('@title').extract()[0]
item['description'] = item_desc
item['title'] = item_desc[:10]
```

If your XPath queries do not always return a result, test for an empty list first:

```
img_match = img.xpath('@src').extract()
item['image'] = img_match[0] if img_match else ''
item_desc = img.xpath('@title').extract()
item['description'] = item_desc[0] if item_desc else ''
item['title'] = item_desc[0][:10] if item_desc else ''
```

Comment: When I try pulling out the 0th element I get an error like this -      item_desc = img.xpath('@title').extract()[0]
 exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @AndrewBucknell: Right, so *some* of your searches do not return an actual title. Test for that first before indexing.

Comment: ah I see whats happening. I was trying so hard to slice the string I was forgetting sometimes its empty. Thank you!